# Can someone explain me how cumulative association in distributed lag models works?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, generalized-additive-model, dlm

I'm trying to fit some distributed lag models with `dlnm` package in R. When I specify `cumul=TRUE`, I obtain extra parameters called `allfit` and `cumfit`, so called overall cumulative association and incremental cumulative association. I always thought that we calculate incremental association just by adding parameter rates to each other, but these values are different. Can someone explain what's the difference between those and what they really are?

```
$coefficients
     p1xv1.l1      p1xv1.l2      p1xv1.l3      p1xv1.l4      p1xv1.l5        p1xv1.l6 
 7.529338e-05  4.517384e-03 -3.622875e-02  1.010654e-01 -1.177784e-01    4.840147e-02

$allfit
           0            1            2 
0.0000000000 0.0002668513 0.0005337026 

$cumfit
          lag0         lag1         lag2         lag3         lag4           lag5
0 0.000000e+00 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000   0.0000000000
1 7.529338e-05 0.0002404799 0.0002748179 0.0003479422 0.0002144081   0.0002668513
2 1.505868e-04 0.0004809598 0.0005496358 0.0006958844 0.0004288163   0.0005337026
```

Comment: Is the [tag:gam] tag relevant here?

Comment: I believe so as GAMs and GLMs are foundation for DLMs estimation. If i'm wrong or it doesn't give any extra information please delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some validation, I found that DLNM will add lag values from "matfit" by row to get "allfit", which means "allfit" is overall association. And DLNM will create "cumfit" according to the cumulative sum of lag days from "matfit". For example, lag1's "cumfit"= lag0's "matfit" + lag1's "matfit".

Here is the validation (you need to get your own crossbasis and model first):

```
pred <- crosspred(crossbasis, model, at=1:20, bylag=1, cumul=TRUE)

#"allfit" sums from "matfit"
View(pred[['allfit']])
rowSums(pred[['matfit']])

#lag1's "cumfit" comes from the sum of the first two columns of "matfit"
View(pred[['cumfit']])
rowSums(pred[['matfit']][,1:2])
```

Comment: It is never too late! After some time I actually found it by myself but it is good to have a confirmation. The cumfit is an accumulated risk from risk for each time point.